# How to configure Chrome browser: modify download directory and turn off pdf viewer

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium

Im using Selenium + C#  to test me web aplication and generate PDF files from it. I have 2 problems:

1) When PDF file is generated, it's displayed in pdf viewer automatically.  I cannot turn it off. It's still enabled after chrome reboot. Im using Chrome v43.0.4. **I want it to be automatically downloaded.**

2) When I save generated PDF file, it's saved in default "Downloads" directory. I read that I should be able to overwrite downlaod path  with Chrome parameters but how?:)

UPDATE 1: When I turned off PDF viewer & changed download path manually, it works after MANUAL Chrome restart, but these values are not working when chrome is started automatically from Selenium.

UDPATE2: Selenium ver 2.49

Answer (score 0):

You can disable pdf viewer typing "about:plugins" into the omnibox at the top, and disabling Chrome PDF Viewer.

To change the download path open chrome settings and change it on advanced options/downloads.

Regards.

Comment: Looks good, but:) when I do automatic test with Selenium, pdf viewer is enabled again. I dont know why.  Generally I'd like to change all these settings from level of tests (C# code).

Comment: Take a look to this link https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=528436, maybe it helps.